# JPA. Создал entity class, не создается таблица

Tags: java, netbeans, jpa

Начал изучать JPA по туториалу.

Один раз все получилось, решил все заново сделать и теперь не получается.

Создал в MySQL базу данных BankDB, создал Web Application и в нем entity class Account, но в таблице не отображаются properties.

То есть в классе Account есть поля id, ownerName и balance, а таблица в MySQL пустая.

Когда нажимаю ctrl+S NetBeans не пишет, что приложение развернуто, а в тот раз когда получилось, появлялось сообщение, что приложение развернуто.

**Вопрос:** кто сталкивался с таким подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Обычно netbeans пишет почему не удалось развернуть приложение. Но раз у Вас он ничего не написал, значит наверное и попытки развёртывания не было. Плохо нажали ctrl+s или за развёртывание отвечает другая комбинация?

Comment: @Николай Беляков Покажите структуру проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что Glassfish сервер не был запущен в то время когда я нажимал "сохранить", поэтому приложение не было развернуто и таблицы не создавались. С запущенным сервером все работает нормально.